# How to know the type of the object boxed in NSValue with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsvalue

I have an NSValue object that can "box" an instance of an unknown type (CGPoint, CGRect, etc.) and I need to determine this type in runtime. How would I do it in Swift?

I tried to do something like this:

```
if ((value as Any) is CGPoint) {}
else if (((value as Any) is CGRect)) {}
...
```

When `value` is a NSValue object containing a CGPoint, it does not get into the if clause.
Then I when I printed `value` it gives me `NSPoint: {150, 150}` which I assume is why it never gets in the clause.

Any ideas why this happens and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's a toll free bridging between NS* and CG*. Have you tried to use NSPoint instead of CGPoint in the if clause? Eg. `if value is NSPoint {`

Comment: I tried that yes, but the compiler does not accept that comparison and I get an error 'Use of undeclared type NSPoint'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, `NSValue`, you so crazy.  Even though `NSRect` etc aren't supposed to be a thing on iOS, if you put a `CGRect` inside an `NSValue`, internally it displays it has an `NSRect` inside it.

Anyway, while they serve similar purposes I don't think you can use `Any` to convert an `NSValue` to or from a `CGPoint` or `CGRect`.  You have to call `value.CGRectValue()` etc.  But to your point, you need to know which it is.  Which also isn't easy, but you can do this:

```
let type = String.fromCString(val.objCType) ?? ""
if type.hasPrefix("{CGRect") {
    let rect = val.CGRectValue()
}
else if type.hasPrefix("{CGPoint") {
    let point = val.CGPointValue()
} //etc...
```

But another question would be, do you really need to use `NSValue`?  It's kind of an Obj-C specific workaround.  Is it being given to you by something you can’t change or might you be better off using `Any` (or even better, generics) instead?

Comment: That is a good point, but I want to simulate the behavior of CAKeyFrameAnimation which has a property 'values' of type [AnyObject]! But anyway, thanks for your solution. That will work.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, iOS doesn't use NSPoint, so that would be a loss.  My best guess for something like this would be to fall back to using objCType, which is how it would be handled in objective-C.  Unfortunately, you don't have access to @encode from swift, so you wind up having to hardcode the possibilities:

```
switch String(CString: value.objCType, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
case "{CGPoint=dd}":  // handle CGPoint here
case "{CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}}": // handle CGRect here
}
```